# Looking for Log4net compatible for .net 1.1 (1.14322)

Tags: .net, logging, log4net

I have been asked to add some logging to a legacy application using .net 1.1 and told to use
Log4net ,can somebody tell me as I could not find out where I can find the download compatible with .net 1.1 (1.14322)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Supporting Frameworks](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html) pages .NET v1.1 is supported.

I just [downloaded 1.2.10](http://archive.apache.org/dist/incubator/log4net/1.2.10/incubating-log4net-1.2.10.zip) and inside that zip was a folder called bin that has net then 1.0 or 1.1 or 2.0...

So folder heirachy was:

```
bin\net\1.0\debug
bin\net\1.0\debug\release
bin\net\1.1\debug
bin\net\1.1\debug\release
bin\net\2.0\debug
bin\net\2.0\debug\release
```

Comment: This was found in one web search and answered in one download. Total time of research: 3 mins. Did you do any searching?

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Log4net

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/